# Laravel polymorphic relationship scope by pivot field

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following polymorphic relationship:

```
// User.php
public function regions()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Region', 'relationship')->withPivot('relationship_level');
}

public function groups()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Group', 'relationship')->withPivot('relationship_level');
}
```

The pivot table is as follows:

```
id | user_id | relationship_id | relationship_type | relationship_level
 1 |      12 |               8 |        App\Region |             master
 2 |      18 |              12 |         App\Group |                fan
```

Is there any way (preferably as scope) where I can get every user who has level "master" when this user can have many `relationship level` to many `relationship_type`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the existing relationships:

```php
User::whereHas('groups', function ($query) {
    $query->where('relationship_level', 'master');
})->orWhereHas('regions', function ($query) {
    $query->where('relationship_level', 'master');
})->get();
```

Using a pivot model and a new relationship (faster):

```php
class Relationship extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphPivot
{
    //
}

class User extends Model
{
    public function relationships()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Relationship::class);
    }
}

User::whereHas('relationships', function ($query) {
    $query->where('relationship_level', 'master');
})->get();
```

Comment: The second solution looks perfect. Should this be `extends MorphPivot`? If so - where is this class comming from?

Comment: I added the namespace. It doesn't have to, it can also extend `Model`. `MorphPivot` is only required in combination with [`using()`](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models).